# Replace a character in all txt files

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to replace the character 'a' with 'o' in all txt files in a directory: "D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\"

For now I use this, but lose time because there are a lot of files.

```
(Get-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\StrEtb.dat).replace('a', 'o') | Set-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\StrEtb.dat
(Get-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\StrEtb2.dat).replace('a', 'o') | Set-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\StrEtb2.dat
....
```

I want something like this:

```
  (Get-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\*).replace('a', 'o') | Set-Content D:\Aither\Pca\Stat\*
```

Is this possible in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$collection = Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Aither\Pca\Stat' -Recurse -Filter '*.dat'

foreach( $file in $collection ) {
   (Get-Content $file.FullName).replace('a', 'o') | Set-Content ($file.FullName) | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Aither\Pca\Stat' -Recurse -Filter "*.dat"`. Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies them when the cmdlet gets the objects rather than having PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-Filter` and `-File` parameters, you will have better performance in collecting the files. Also, you can use a `ForEach-Object` to simply pipe these files through to the next cmdlet.

Because you are overwriting the file(s), you need to use brackets around `Get-Content`, so you are not trying to read and write to the same file at the same time.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Aither\Pca\Stat' -Filter '*.dat' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content).Replace('a', 'o') | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```